Docker buildx --build-context equivalent for Kaniko
I need to build an image with Kaniko from a Dockerfile however I need to override the "FROM" instruction. This is possible with docker buildx or buildah via the --build-context option.
Is this possible with kaniko or does it miss this feature?
